# Can all files in System32 be trusted on Windows?

Tags: windows, virus

So, when a virus got it's way to my computer, I decided to hunt it down by looking at the list of currenty running tasks in Task Manager. Probably not the best way, but that was my approach.

A lot of executables that were running were in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory. I understand that is a Windows directory for the OS. But can a program add an executable there?

In other words, can a virus put there executable in that directory, with or without administrator permissions? Or is that directory exclusively reserved for the OS?

Comment: No not all files can be trusted in that folder just because they are there. Yes viruses can get into this folder with and without admin access. A virus can be put in there while the Windows OS is not booted. It's all a matter of what level of protection you are looking for and what data you are trying to protect, etc.

Comment: "can a virus put there executable in that directory, with or without administrator permissions?" - Yes, this can happen, which is the reason you are not suppose to run as an Administrator all the time.  System32 can contain any file you want it to contain as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### System32 is a trusted folder if...

On a Windows installation in a default configuration, only processes with administrative-level permissions can create files in the System32 folder. Therefore you can trust the code running from that directory if the following are true:

- Only trustworthy programs have been installed on the computer. (I am here referring only to programs that required elevation to install.)
- The system has not been compromised with an elevation of privilege vulnerability.

This second point is difficult to be confident of, especially in cases where malicious software is suspected. For example, a threat could have started under a non-privileged account, used a vulnerability to gain administrative permissions, then installed a root kit to hide its presence. The system admin may have good reason to suspect something's afoot, but not be readily able to confirm or deny possible use of an elevation of privilege exploit.

Of course someone who uses their system on a daily basis logged in with an administrative level account makes it significant easier for malicious code to compromise the whole system and is probably better off assuming they're screwed at first sign of unwanted activity.

---

#### Not all code running from System32 is what it seems

Approaching this from another angle is the possibility that as you inspect your system for malicious processes you may *think* code is running from System32 when in fact it is not.

Even on a machine where unwanted software never had admin permissions it can give the casual observer the impression it is running from the System32 folder. It does this by placing a malicious DLL in a unprivileged location (e.g. the AppData folder structure), then executes DLLHOST.EXE (a Microsoft executable which resides in System32), passing the name of the DLL as an argument. Because the running process is DLLHOST.EXE, everything appears legitimate. It's only on closer inspection that one would discover the actual code, contained in the DLL, is not in a normally-privileged location and therefore suspect.

The good news is that in cases like this where malicious code didn't get admin permissions, it cannot break out of the originally infected user's account by configuring Windows to start it for all users. Therefore such threats can easily be eliminated by logging in with an uncompromised account and doing the cleanup from there.